# I am trying to limit the decimal places of the value outputted

Tags: tofixed

What I have at the moment is a script that out puts a value after adding together different input fields.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#addAll").click(function() {
            var add = 0;
            $(".amt").each(function() {
                add += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $("#para").html("&#36;<input size=&quot;18&quot; name=&quot;salestax&quot; class=&quot;amt&quot; readonly type=&quot;text&quot; value=" + add + " />");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to limit the decimal place of this output to only 2 decimal places.

What do I need to add? I assume its the toFixed() but I have tried that in numerous places. Where should it be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always avoid reducing the precision of your floating point values until as late as possible. In your case, you want to apply `toFixed()` in the line that constructs the display HTML. Also, you are missing quote marks around the value attribute. Your code should look something like this:

```
$("#para").html("&#36;<input size=&quot;18&quot; name=&quot;salestax&quot; class=&quot;amt&quot; readonly type=&quot;text&quot; value=&quot;" + add.toFixed(2) + "&quot; />");
```

I'm not sure that `&quot;` is really necessary, I think you could just use apostrophes instead (`'`).